# My Image from Server becomes NULL

Tags: php, android, mysql, bitmap, android-asynctask

I am using PHP to upload my image to MySQL server and it uploads well.

But the problem comes when downloading it. I have tested the link from which I download & the image comes hunky-dory but displaying it in ImageView becomes a tedious task. It is not showing any error in LogCat window. The bitmap becomes null (I compared it using `bitmap==null`)

**My DoInBackground and OnPostExecute**

```
        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
            String id = params[0];
            String add = "http://dakshansh.com/mybooks/image/getImage.php?id=" + imageId;
            Log.d("Image","Link = "+add);
            URL url = null;
            Bitmap image = null;
            try {
                url = new URL(add);
                image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return image;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap b) {
            super.onPostExecute(b);
            //loading.dismiss();
            if(b==null){
                Log.d("Image","Image is null");
            }
            Log.d("Image","On onPostExecute()");
            image.setImageBitmap(b);
            Log.d("Image", "Image Set");
            new ReadJSONFeedTask1().execute("http://dakshansh.com/mybooks/books/getmybooks.php?posterid="+id);


        }
```

I will post anything more if you require it.
You can see the image [here](http://dakshansh.com/mybooks/image/getImage.php?id=107)

Comment: Just an friendly advice. Use Picasso or Glide to process images.

Comment: Agreed with Anton, it will save you a lot of headache down the road. Back on topic however, are you getting an IOException with the code?

Comment: Whatis in the `url.openConnection().getInputStream()` stream? Do you even have data in there?

Comment: It works in other Activities. So I don't think so I should change

Comment: Yes @Shark and I am not getting any exception

Comment: I am not getting exception!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use glide it will save alot of time for you

```
 ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.my_image_view);

   Glide.with(this).load("your_url").into(imageView);
```

more [here](https://github.com/bumptech/glide)

Comment: What's `Glide`. I can't understand github. Give complete code if you can. Glide becomes red

Comment: add this to your gradle `compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0' ` and the most basic way to use the libaray is 
`Glide.with(MyActivity.this).load("your_url").into(your_image_view);`